# Finding Referring DLL in a project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dll, projects-and-solutions

I am working on large scale application which contains lot of projects in it. I am trying to replace one 3rd Party DLL with the other one. I need to find where are all that DLL is being referred in the entire application. I am currently checking all the code base for references which is very difficult and also I may miss some where.

Is there any easy and optimal way or any external tool to find the references?

Any Ideas would help?

Comment: Does that third party utility comes with upgrade utility? If yes then try to upgrade using that. Else just replace dll and build , this will hopefully produce list of errors to solve.

Comment: No upgrade utility. To replacing it I just need to find it references right? My question is actually finding the references.

Comment: Backup your working copy first. Then delete old dll. Compile/Build. This will give you errors and indicators in solution where and which project you want new dll to be placed

Comment: There's also looking at the vproj file. It will go form by form to tell you embedded resources, but I usually follow what Amit said.

Comment: Ok Thanks.. Someone post as Answer and I will accept it..